# Attempt to access the method failed on WP7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, stream, pdf-reader

I wanna use PDFSharp for WP7 library but it throws an exception like that

> "Attempt to access the method failed: PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocumentInformation..ctor(PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDictionary)"

A part of my codes is below:

```
IsolatedStorageFile resurce = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

Stream str = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("test7.pdf", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, resurce)).BaseStream;
                PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
                document.Version = 14;
                document = PdfReader.Open(str);
```

EDIT: I found an answer. The problem was `document = PdfReader.Open(str);`. The solution is `document = PdfReader.Open(str, PdfDocumentOpenMode.ReadOnly);`. you can change OpenMode.

Comment: Great question, but please format your code as code by putting four spaces before it.

Comment: thank you for warning i will be more careful, what is your answer? :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have an answer. Stack Overflow has a review queue for the first post by new users and your question was one of them. (See http://stackoverflow.com/review/). The goal of the process is to help new users learn to use the site and I commented on your question. Good question, but sorry, I don't have an answer.